# Webview open a wrong link in android

Tags: android, webview

I want to open a google search with a keyword from a textbox. The link is somewhat looks like this

```
http://www.google.com.vn/#hl=vi&output=search&q= + keyword
```

Then I call the `mWebView (WebView object)` with the following code:

```
mWebView.loadUrl(link);
```

after this point, the webview appears (I put it in a popupwindow) with the google page (not the result of query above). I don't know what wrong with this.

Comment: can you post your `link` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like,

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/search?q="+value);
```

If its not working then post your link url..

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not reading the content from text box, or not appending it to the link?

Comment: sorry for forgetting posting the link, my fault